# do we have conditional insert or update in db2 like we have if else in sql?

Tags: sql, merge, db2

I want to check if we already have a record exist in table , if yes then run update query else insert query should be executed in db2 databse.

Comment: It is called merge: 
 https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0010873.html

Comment: Please provide more details, table structures, what you have tried for starters.

Comment: Okay.. So I have a menu table where I need to insert one menu. But it should be inserted only when that doesn't exist in that table.

Comment: This Merge query is working fine. Thanks Gordon!